# 'TypeError: el.addEventListener is not a function.' in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I am trying to follow a youtube video on developing a kanban board in react-native, the video tutorial is for react and I am very new to react and react-native or even javascript in general.

App.tsx :

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {Text, SafeAreaView, Image, Animated, View, Button, StyleSheet,Pressable,TextInput,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable} from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
//import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';

const itemsFromBackend = [
  {id: "1", content: 'Task1'},
  {id: "2", content: 'Task2'}
];

const columnsFromBackend = [
  {
    'Todo':{
      name : 'Todo',
      items : itemsFromBackend
    }

  }
];

const Kanban = () => {

const [columns, setColumns] = useState(columnsFromBackend)
return(
  <SafeAreaView style = {styles.container} >
    
    <SafeAreaView style= {styles.header_img}>
      <Image  style= {styles.images} source = {require('./assets/Kanban-board-1.png')}></Image>
    </SafeAreaView>
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.header}>
      <Image  style= {styles.images} source = {require('./assets/to_do.png')}></Image>
    </SafeAreaView>

    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
      <Text>CONTENT 1</Text>
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={result=> console.log(result)}>
        {Object.entries(columns).map(([id, column]) => {
          return(
            <Droppable droppableId={id}>
              {(provided, snapshot) => {
                return(
                  <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef} style={{
                    backgroundColor: snapshot.isDraggingOver ? 'lightblue' : 'lightgrey',
                    padding: 4,
                    width: 250,
                    minHeight: 500
                  }}>
                    {column.Todo.items.map((item, index) => {
                      return(
                        <Draggable key={item.id} draggableId={item.id} index={index}>
                          {(provided,snapshot) => {
                            return(
                              <div {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps} style={{
                                userSelect: 'none',
                                padding: 16,
                                margin: '0 0 8px 0',
                                minHeight: '50px',
                                backgroundColor: snapshot.isDragging ? 'yellow' : 'orange',
                                color: 'black',
                                ...provided.draggableProps.style
                              }}>
                                {item.content}
                              </div>
                            );
                          }}
                        </Draggable>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                )
              }}
            </Droppable>
          );
          }
        )
        }
      </DragDropContext>
    </SafeAreaView>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
};

{/* ===================== STYLING COMPONENTS =====================*/}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

container : {flex:1,
borderWidth:5
},

images: {height:100,
resizeMode:"contain",
  width:300
  },

header : {
  flex:1,
  justifyContent:"center",
  alignItems:"center",
  borderWidth:1,
  margin:1,
  padding: 1
},

header_img : {flex:2,
  justifyContent:"center",
  alignItems:"center",
  borderWidth:1,
  margin:1,
  padding: 1
  },

  threebox : {flex:4,
  flexDirection:"row",
  borderWidth:1}
  
});


export default Kanban;
```

The following errors are popping up in the error logs of the server when I do 'expo start' from the expo-cli and render the app using my phone or browser:-

```
Error
15:30
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Kanban`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
Connect(Droppable)@http://2y-38e.amalmajeed.kanban-notes.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:127744:43
    in Kanban (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer

Stack trace:
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:174:8 in registerError
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:34:4 in console.error
  node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
  node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:117:4 in printWarning
  node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:93:16 in error
  node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:986:9 in validateExplicitKey
  node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1013:29 in validateChildKeys
  node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1184:27 in jsxWithValidation
  App.tsx:43:6 in Kanban
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10121:26 in renderWithHooks
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13183:27 in mountIndeterminateComponent
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19794:22 in beginWork$1
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18563:22 in performUnitOfWork
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18499:21 in workLoopSync
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18464:18 in renderRootSync
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18158:31 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
  [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5911:33 in runWithPriority$argument_1
  node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5906:23 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5893:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17745:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21484:23 in updateContainer
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:22144:17 in render
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/renderApplication.js:58:4 in renderApplication
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:117:25 in runnables.appKey.run
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:202:4 in runApplication
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __callFunction
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:113:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
Error
15:30
TypeError: el.addEventListener is not a function. (In 'el.addEventListener(binding.eventName, binding.fn, options)', 'el.addEventListener' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in ErrorBoundary (created by DragDropContext)
    in DragDropContext (created by Kanban)
    in RCTSafeAreaView
    in SafeAreaView (created by Kanban)
    in RCTSafeAreaView
    in SafeAreaView (created by Kanban)
    in Kanban (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer

Stack trace:
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:149:8 in registerError
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:34:4 in console.error
  node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15792:34 in logCapturedError
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15884:20 in update.callback
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7199:2 in callCallback
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7220:20 in commitUpdateQueue
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16632:25 in commitLifeCycles
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19216:22 in commitLayoutEffects
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:93:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackProd
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:318:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18952:29 in commitRootImpl
  [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
  node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18791:17 in commitRoot
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18192:12 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
  [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5911:33 in runWithPriority$argument_1
  node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5906:23 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5893:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17745:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21484:23 in updateContainer
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:22144:17 in render
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/renderApplication.js:58:4 in renderApplication
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:117:25 in runnables.appKey.run
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:202:4 in runApplication
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __callFunction
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:113:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
Error
15:30
TypeError: el.addEventListener is not a function. (In 'el.addEventListener(binding.eventName, binding.fn, options)', 'el.addEventListener' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in ErrorBoundary (created by DragDropContext)
    in DragDropContext (created by Kanban)
    in RCTSafeAreaView
    in SafeAreaView (created by Kanban)
    in RCTSafeAreaView
    in SafeAreaView (created by Kanban)
    in Kanban (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer

Stack trace:
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:149:8 in registerError
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:34:4 in console.error
  node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
  node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:165:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
  node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:123:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:177:14 in _callImmediatesPass
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:437:30 in callImmediates
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:388:6 in __callImmediates
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:132:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:131:4 in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
```

Here is my 'package.json' file for the project :

```
    {
  "name": "kanban-notes",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-draganddrop-board": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.2",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Not sure how to proceed from here, kindly let me know how to get rid of this ?

P.S : I use VS CODE in Mac to run the expo-cli

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `react-beautiful-dnd` does not support `react-native`, as it tries to call `addEventListener`. Since `react-native` doesn't run in the context of a browser, there is no Web APIs and thus no DOM.